# Pogo Pins for 1.5mm Pitch Test Fixture

Tags: pins, testing, test, production-testing, dfm

I'm working on a design and am going to source a smaller pcb and solder it to my design.

Before using the sourced board I'm wanting to test it and so I'm trying to design a test fixture similar in concept to the ones described in this [Spark Fun Tutorial.](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/138)

Here's a drawing of the pads along the outside of the board I need to connect to for the test:

[image: board I need to test]

The board that I'm sourcing is gold plated. The pads are on both the top and bottom of the board - but larger on the bottom - so I assume it's better to try to go the pogo pin route from either the top or the sides.

Here's a zoomed image of the pads from the bottom. (my apologies for an image that's slightly blurry)

[image]

So first off I wonder if I should follow the spark fun tutorial and try to make a board that will connect to the pads from the bottom or perhaps I should try to get some type of pogo pin to try to go into the drilled portion of the pad at say a right angle. (finding a right angle pogo pin at 1.5 mm might be impossible in itself)

Anyway looking at the spark fun pogo pins they have some [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9174) but it's head size is 1.3mm so I'm thinking I'm asking for trouble using something with just .2mm clearance between heads.

I was wondering if anyone had experience using a pogo pin for this type of spacing and pads and what you'd recommend?

Thanks in advance.

-J

Answer (score 1):

There are few companies which make pogo pins for such small pitch. you can use a 1.5mm crimp housing connector as a quick hack, slide the pins through it and you have a ready made 1.5mm  pitch test jig. However, a better approach would be to arrange the pins in a zigzag pattern (might not be possible in your case).
Here is a 1.27mm pitch pogo: http://www.idinet.com/Test-Probes/Loaded-Board-Probes/ICT-Advantage/ICT-50C.aspx/